# History prop of react router getting executed itself on page load

Tags: react-router-v4

I am learning react router@v4 and came across an unexpected scenario while running my code. It is as follows:

I wrote below lines to navigate to another component:

```
<NavLink to="/data">Dummy Data</NavLink>
<Route path="/data" component={DataStore} history={history} />
```

In it history inside {} is a const variable referring to createBrowserHistory() of React. On DataStore page I wrote a button code with onclick function as below:

```
<button onClick={this.props.history.push("/")}>Back</button>
```

When I click Dummy Data link on main page control redirects to DataStore component and without any action it goes back to the main page after finishing page load action. Means the code specified for onClick function is executed, without clicking the button, on page load itself. To overcome this issue I wrote different function in DataStore component which I called on button click and in it I wrote "this.props.history.push('/')". I then again run my code and it worked fine.

Can anyone guide me about the above specified unusual behavior of react history function on page load. Would be very thankful for a helping response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onClick={this.props.history.push("/")}>Back</button>
```

will be executed immediately

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.history.push("/")}>Back</button>
```

will be executed on click

Comment: Plz explain why first onclick statement would be executed immediately and not the second one. Normally in javascript, action specified for an event listener function is executed when that event occurs and not immediately on page load but it does not happen so in react. Why so ?

Comment: generally in JSX inside curly-braces is this normal behavior. You need to return function like a callback which is done by `{push}` or `{()=>push()}` but `{push()}` will execute immediately. Another example is `<p>{someFormatingFunction('Hello')} world<p>` Here you see that you need that function to be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer and the link with. I understood the concept behind my query now properly.